# Display an input in a p tag without changing the font

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a font previewer where user can input a specific word and change its font on the basis of the selected font. I have made the whole thing, but am stuck in the last moment.

I have made a live preview of the font changing in the input. now I want to output the input in the selected font in a p tag. I can't figure out what to do.

Please ignore all my English mistakes. Thank you.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const fontListElement = document.querySelector('#fonts');

const controls_selectedFont = document.querySelector('.selected-font');
let fontListFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=popularity&key=AIzaSyD2XlgdSV2aMaFApwYwRZPGty_5PDSUaZA')
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((fontsObject) => {
    for (font of fontsObject.items) {
      let fontFamily = font.family;
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.classList.add('font');
      li.setAttribute('data-value', fontFamily);
      li.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
      li.innerText = fontFamily;
      li.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;

      fontListFragment.appendChild(li);
    }

    fontListElement.appendChild(fontListFragment);


    let chunkedFonts = chunk(fontsObject.items, 12);

    let importStatements = chunkedFonts
      .map((chunkedFontsArr) => {
        return `@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${chunkedFontsArr
          .map((f) => f.family)
          .join('|')}"`;
      })
      .join(';');

    let fontsStyle = document.createElement('style');
    fontsStyle.type = 'text/css';
    fontsStyle.innerHTML = importStatements;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fontsStyle);
  });

fontListElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (isFontListItem(e.srcElement)) {
    let li = e.srcElement;
    let fontFamily = li.dataset.value;
    content.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    selectedFont(fontFamily);
    copyButton(fontFamily);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});

fontListElement.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 9 && isFontListItem(e.target)) document.activeElement.click();
});

function isFontListItem(clickedElm) {
  return clickedElm.classList.contains('font');
}

function chunk(ar, size) {
  let buffer = [];
  return ar.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
    let isLast = i === ar.length - 1;

    if (buffer.length === size) {
      let theChunk = [...buffer];
      buffer = [item];
      return [...acc, theChunk];
    } else {
      buffer.push(item);
      if (isLast) {
        return [...acc, buffer];
      } else {
        return acc;
      }
    }
  }, []);
}

function searchFonts() {
  var input, filter, font, i, txtValue;
  input = document.querySelector("#font-search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  font = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < font.length; i++) {
    txtValue = font[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      font[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      font[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function selectedFont(fontName) {
  controls_selectedFont.innerText = fontName;
}

function checkSpace(font) {
  return font.replace(/\s/g, '+');
}

function init() {
  controls_selectedFont.innerText = 'Please select a font...';
}
init();

var word = document.getElementById('content'),
  originalStory = document.getElementById('story'),
  button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

button.onclick = function() {
  replaceStory(word.value);
};

var replaceStory = function(userWord) {
  var story = ("A " + userWord + " is now part of the story");

  return originalStory.innerHTML = story;
};
```

```css
aside {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

aside .selected-font,
span {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

aside .search-font {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

aside .search-font input {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

aside #fonts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  list-style: none;
}

aside #fonts li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 50%;
}

#content:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <aside>
      <span><strong>Current Font:</strong></span><br>
      <div class="selected-font"></div>
      <div class="search-font">
        <input type="text" id="font-search" aria-label="Search fonts" placeholder="Search...." onkeyup="searchFonts()">
      </div>

      <ul id="fonts"></ul>

    </aside>
  </div>
  <div>

    <input type="text" name="fontTxtField" id="content" class="fontTxtField" placeholder="Your text here" /></div>
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="submitButton"></input>
  <p id="story"> A {userWord} is now part of the story </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p contenteditable="true">This is an editable paragraph.</p>` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question seems fine for now, but I'd recommend keeping these as a future reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond. I never use stackoverflow before. I thought it will take 3-4 days to get a normal ans. But I get my answer so fast it's really unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy/paste the content of your input in a p with Javascript.

I listen for keydown in the input, then I change the innerHTML of the p elements that have the same class.

Beware that, you'll lose your first sentence, so if you delete the content of the input, you'll end up with a blank p. Maybe you can add an if to use your basic sentences if nothing is written in the input.

You can also use contenteditable, as said by secan, to let the user try other sentences with a specific font.

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
    const textToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.fontTrial');
    myInput.addEventListener('keydown', changeText, false);

    function changeText(){
      const inputContent = this.value;
      textToChange.forEach(function(el){
        el.innerHTML = inputContent;
      })
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Change the content">
<p class="fontTrial" contenteditable="true">This is a basic text.</p>
<p class="fontTrial" contenteditable="true">Another text to edit.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. The code worked but it doesn't change the font. Plz help me

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I tried the code but it doesn't change the selected font.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're building this project but Javascript frameworks like Angular, React and Vue make this type of thing trivial.

However in straight javascript, you really just need to track when the input changes and apply the value to another HTML element (it doesn't really matter what type of element).

Here's a very basic example:

```js
var theText = document.getElementById('sourceText');
var thePreview = document.getElementById('previewText');

theText.addEventListener("keyup", updateText)

function updateText(){
 thePreview.innerHTML = theText.value;
}
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-family: "Times Roman", serif
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sourceText" placeholder="change this text" value="" />
<div>
   <p id="previewText"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I tried the code but it doesn't change the selected font.